# write locator for the web element in protractor using selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, xpath, protractor

Hi I have tried to write the locator for this initiated text element .which is having span tag inside the div.
it has parent tag as `<P-header>`
I tried till this.

```
$.(p.header).$(span.nth-child(2));
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
    <p-header _ngcontent-bok-c3 class="banner">
     <ka-country _ngcontent_bok-ce _nghost-bok-c4>
         <div _ngcontent-bok-c4 class="country"></div>
     </ka-country>
     <span _ngcontent-bok-c3>
       <span _ngcontent-bok-c3 class"sakdjghsdfg">
           <span _ngcontent-bok-c3 class"sakdjghsdfg"></span>
           <span _ngcontent-bok-c3 class"sakdjghsdfg"></span>
           <a _ngcontent-bok-c3 class="sadfgfasdf"</a>
           <span _ngcontent-bok-c3 class"sakdjghsdfg"></span>
           <span _ngcontent-bok-c3 class"sakdjghsdfg"></span>
      </span>
    </span>
  <div _ngcontent-bok-c3 class="asdkjhfds">
        <span _ngcontent-bok-c3 class"sakdjghsdfg"></span> "INITIATED"    
 </div>
</p-header>
```

Comment: Share HTML as text, not photo

Comment: please check now.

Comment: Did you try to replace `$.(p.header)` with `$(p-header)`?

Comment: yes i tried $.(p-header).$(span.nth-child(2)) but didn't worked.

Comment: $.(p.header).$$(span.nth-child).get(2) will probably work.

Comment: if you rewrite your question neatly, it will be easier to understand your problem and you'll have higher chances getting the answer